# AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'

Tags: python

Below is my code I am merging ~ delimited files and saving them in xlsx format but getting error

align_format = workbook.add_format()
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'

I am using Python 3.6.8

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import os
import sys
import glob
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl


def testfunc(target_filename):
table_list = []

for filename in glob.glob("E:\\dev\\Python_Dev\\Python368\\*.dat"):
    print(filename)
    table_list.append(filename)

writer = ExcelWriter(target_filename, engine=None)

for sheet in table_list:
    (_, f_name) = os.path.split(sheet)
    (f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    df = pd.read_csv(sheet, delimiter='~', encoding='unicode_escape')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f_short_name, index=False)

    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[f_short_name]
    align_format = workbook.add_format()
    align_format.set_align('center')

writer.save()
writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   test_func(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: I see the method you are looking for on this: XlsxWriter  but not on the pandas ExcelWriter.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that `Workbook` objects don't have an attribute `add_format`. You need to look at the documentation more carefully.

Comment: @LhasaDad, installed xlsxwriter package that fixed the issue

Comment: @RahulWagh Would you like me to add that as the answer to your question?

Comment: @LhasaDad,yes please

Comment: @RahulWagh Added the answer.  please feel free to accept/upvote

Answer (score 3):

Several answers explain how to fix this (`pip install xlsxwriter`) but not why it is failing in the first place. The reason is that you aren't specifying the ExcelWriter engine to use:

```py
writer = ExcelWriter(target_filename, engine=None)
```

In this case Pandas will default to whichever xlsx writer modules are installed. The options, in order, are `xlsxwriter` and `openpyxl`. Further down in your code you use `workbook.add_format()` which is an `xlsxwriter` method. So if you wish to use that module's syntax you should specify the engine explicitly:

```py
writer = ExcelWriter(target_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
```

This will still fail is `xlsxwriter` isn't installed but at least the reason will be clearer to the user/maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
pip install xlsxwriter
```

fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see the method you are looking for on this: XlsxWriter but not on the pandas ExcelWriter.

I would suggest making sure you have that package available and are using it.

Answer (score 1):

align_format = workbook.add_worksheet() may solve your problem